# Где будет правильно расположить методы конвертации дто -> ентити и наоборот?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

Думал над несколькими вариантами:

1. Разместить прямо в дто в каждом.
2. Создать отдельный класс DTOUtils и все туда скинуть ( но тогда там вперемешку будут методы конвертации всех классов )
3. Сделать пакет dtoutils и там создать много классов ( для каждого дто свой, они будут только хранить дто методы и все )

Третий вариант выглядит как самый благоразумный, но создавать отдельный класс для одного метода это как-то не очень

P.S. Можно ли в классе-маппере разместить репозиторий, если это необходимо для конвертации ДТО-Ентии? Или это плохой тон?

Comment: Для каждой сущности сделать свой класс-маппер?

Comment: Например, OrderMapper будет маппить Order куда и откуда требуется

Comment: Так вы избежите класса с миллионом методов, класс бредёт сфокусирован на конкретной сущности, класс сможете ещё и замокать без проблем для тестов, да и сам маппер будет небольшой, а это легче тестировать

Comment: Можно маппер на уровне контроллера сделать, если он не сложный и не создавать отдельный класс

Comment: @tym32167, благодарю, выходит, надо создать отдельный пакет классов-маперов? Хотел бы еще один вопрос уточнить, мне для конвертации ДТО-Ентии нужна БД. Если я инстанс репозитория кину в один из маперов это будет пример плохого тона? Так вообще можно? Или вся связь с репозиторием только через сервис и нужно создать мапер, который уже принимает все необходимое.

Comment: Выбрать фреймворк, в котором конвертация данных  является встроенной концепцией и имеет возможность расширения и кастомизации. Изобретать велосипед иногда полезно, но только для общего развития.

Comment: ну по идее это имеет смысл, держать пакет для мапперов, но я думаю, это зависит все от того, как вы структурируете ваш проект. У вас будет пакет для репозиториев? для дто? для энтити? Если да, то вы уже сами по идее складываете классы с похожим назначением по пакетам.

Comment: маппер должен только маппить. Он должен получать класс и отдавать класс. Логичто будет, если один маппер будет использовать другой. Не логично пихать базу данных в мапперы. Готовьте все нужные данные для маппинга заранее, и пусть маппер уже никуда не лезет за данными

Comment: Сами мапперы вы не обязвны писать руками. Есть наверняка много всяких библиотек на эту тему. Вот, например, генератор мапперов https://mapstruct.org/

Comment: согласен с идеей отдельных классов-мепперов. я так делал со спрингом. у них у всех делается общий интерфейс с методами toDto, toModel ,интерфейс типизируется двумя дженериками модель-дто. поскольку в меппере только состояние, то он легко становится бином и потом инжектится в переменную типа интерфейса по дженерику. а если вы еще и грамотно строите сервис леер, то это все вообще на абстрактном уровне происходит. кодаминимум и все прозрачно. а вот с мепперами из коробки негативный опыт. не советую

Answer (score 0):

Одним из правил "чистой архитектуры" является разделение логики по уровням.
Отделение абстракции от реализации.
Ваши Entity - конкретная реализация того как вы работаете с БД.
Сейчас вы работаете с JPA, через месяц захотите использовать например JDBC для более тонкого управления работой с БД, через 2 месяца вообще решите отказаться от SQL и перейти на NoSQL, так вот такие "переходы" не должны вызывать больших трудозатрат.

Если в вашей логике вы работаете только с DTO и Entity определите интерфейс

```
public interface IUserRepository {

    UserDto findById(Long userId);

    List<UserDto> findAll();

}
```

Это простой пример разграничения логики. В реализации IUserRepository вы можете исползовать UserEntity, репозитории от JPA, так же на этом уровне вы можете определить маппер для конвертации Entity в DTO для User.
Таким образом ваша бизнес-логика не будет зависеть от способа хранения данных и при переходе единственное что вам необходимо будет изменить - реализацию вашего IUserRepository